# Function for generically controlling 'Manipulate' parameters

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I want to use a generic function to generate controls in manipulate, which looks like this:

```
lincontrol[variable_, default_, min_, max_] :=
 {{{variable, default}, min, max}, 
  Panel[ToString[variable ] <> "=" Dynamic[variable]]}
```

so that I can use it inside a module like this:

```
    Manipulate[Module[{spectrum},
  spectrum = y^2 + a*x + b;
  Plot[spectrum, {x, -10, 10}]],
 Flatten[{lincontrol[#, 1, 0, 10] &/@ {y,a,b}}, 2]]
```

The idea is that `lincontrol` would generate a controller and display panel for `y,a,b`. The problem is that `lincontrol` is returning a list, whereas `Manipulate` just wants to take a series of arguments. I've used `Flatten` to get rid of the extra list layers, but I can't remove the 'outer' list. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Evaluate[Sequence @@ 
  Flatten[{lincontrol[#, 1, 0, 10] & /@ {y, a, b}}, 2]]`

Comment: Something is wrong with `spectrum = (x=y^2 +a*b;`. You have no closing parenthesis. Maybe you mean `x*y^2+a*b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do; however, this is how to use a variable number of controls.

```
lincontrol[variable_, default_, min_, max_] :=
 {{variable, default}, min, max,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}

Manipulate[
 Module[
  {spectrum},
  spectrum = y^2 + a*x + b;
  Plot[spectrum, {x, -10, 10},
   PlotRange -> {-100, 210}]],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ (
    lincontrol[#, 1, 0, 10] & /@
     {y, a, b})]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to show the current value for each control variable close to the control, and you constructed a `Panel` object to show that, which didn't seem to work.

I wonder if this alternative solution would work for you instead:

Clear[lincontrol]

```
lincontrol[variable_, default_, min_, max_] := 
    {{variable, default, ToString[variable] <> " ="}, min, max, Appearance -> "Labeled"}

Manipulate[
  Module[{spectrum},
    spectrum = x*y^2 + a*b;
    Plot[spectrum, {x, -10, 10}]
  ],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ (lincontrol[#, 1, 0, 10] & /@ {y, a, b})]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could of course achieve the same results from within `Manipulate` as well, but your `lincontrol` function saves you some typing.

Notice also that I modified your definition of `spectrum` arbitrarily so it would be correct syntactically.